# Angular controller doesn´t display the data

Tags: angularjs

I´m quite newbie developing an Angular app.

I have two views:

1. Main: Searches for elements.
2. Results: Shows the query results.

The searcher form is in a view, and it´s included in both (Main and Results) views. Both views are linked to the same controller.

The problem is when I click on search in the main view, the service is called and the values returned, however the results are not displayed in the results view.

If I execute the same query in the results view, the everything works ok and the results are shown.

The code:

Main view and results include exactly same seacher view:

```
<div ng-include src="'partials/boat-searcher.html'" class="text-center"></div>
```

Searcher view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="departure" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in cities($viewValue)" class="input-xlarge input-height-large" placeholder="Salida" autocomplete="off">
```

My app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {    
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'BoatListCtrl'});        
    $routeProvider.when('/option-list', {templateUrl: 'partials/option-list.html', controller: 'BoatListCtrl'});
  }]);
```

My controller:

```
.controller('BoatListCtrl', function BoatListCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams, $http, Boat, Equipment, Extra) {
// Departures typeahead
        $scope.departure = undefined;       
        $scope.cities = function(cityName) {            
            return $http.get("http://localhost:3000/departures?query="+cityName).then(function(response){               
                var names = response.data.map(function (source) { return source.name; });                
                return names;
            });
        };      


        // Gets options (boats)
        $scope.getOptionList = function(departure, fechaSalida, fechaLlegada, personas) {                       
            $scope.boats = Boat.query({departure: departure, fechaSalida: fechaSalida, fechaLlegada: fechaLlegada, personas: personas});    
            $location.path('/option-list');                                         
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved by myself. So, I will explain how I did it:

1. View with query form:

   ```
   <form class="form-search">      
   <input type="text" ng-model="departure" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in cities($viewValue)" class="input-xlarge input-height-large" placeholder="Salida" autocomplete="off">
   // Your form query fields                                
   <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="getOptionList(departure, fechaSalida, fechaLlegada, personas)"><i class="icon-search icon-white icon-small"></i> Buscar</button>
   ```
2. In my HomeCtrl (this is the controller where I query, but I want to display in another view with another controller:

   ```
   .controller('HomeCtrl', function HomeCtrl($scope, $location, $http, $filter, Boat, BoatService, SearcherService) {

       // Gets options (boats)
       $scope.getOptionList = function(departure, departureDate, arrivalDate, people) {                        
           $scope.formattedDepartureDate  = $filter('date')(departureDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');           
           $scope.formattedArrivalDate = $filter('date')(arrivalDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');              
           $scope.people = people;             
           $scope.boats = Boat.query({departure: departure, departureDate: $scope.formattedDepartureDate, arrivalDate: $scope.formattedArrivalDate, people: $scope.people});               
           BoatService.setBoats($scope.boats);     
           $location.path('/option-list');                                         
       };
   })
   ```

Note: Here is important to note, I get the list of boats to a scope variable and I set it in a service with BoatService.setBoats (this service will be available for next controller to get the boats.)

1. My boat-list.html view

   ```
   <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat='boat in boats'>
     {{boat.name}}
     ...
   ```
2. BoatListCtrl (to show the boats in another view):

   ```
    .controller('BoatListCtrl', function BoatListCtrl($scope, $location, $http, $filter, SearcherService, Boat, BoatService, Equipment, Extra, 
                                                     Rating, Comment, Booking, BookingService) {               

       $scope.boats = BoatService.getBoats();
     };
   ```